# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'form-login'

Tags: xml, spring, spring-security

XML:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth-1.0.xsd">
.........
<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
</beans>
```

I am getting this error on line `form-login`:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'form-login'

Can anyone please provide a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The default namespace in your XML is `beans`, so you can ignore the `beans`, but the `form-login` belongs to `security` namespace. More about the namespace see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp).

```xml
<security:form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
```